# Samsung Galaxy S2 AVD - Official skin, how to render correct dimensions

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, galaxy

I have installed the official Samsung Galaxy S2 skin thanks to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings), in Eclipse.

The problem I have is that it doesn't render my app anywhere near the resolution of the actual device when running in the Emulator, surely this is the point of using the skin.

Please see the screenshots and settings I'm using, where am I going wrong?

**Emulator output - API 11**

[image: skin output]

**Emulator output - API 15**

[image]

**Device screenshot**

[image: actual device output]

**AVD settings - automatically generated by the skin**

[image: skin settings]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing Abstracted LCD density hardware argument from 300 to 218 ppi.

Comment: YES YES YES - perfect, I edited the hardware.ini file in the skin using 218ppi as suggested. Thank you very much for your persistence and help!!

Answer (score 1):

In AVD Manager, select your Galaxy SII emulator, click the "Start..." button and then in the Launch Options dialog configure the display as follows:

[image: Galaxy SII emulator launch configuration]

Comment: Although this does show the "skin" at the exact size as the device, the contents are still the same, it only shows 4 lines in my list and the title is truncated, any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I see that your AVD target is Android 3.0 but the GUI on your physical device looks different. Make sure to test using an emulator with the same Android version and theme than your real phone.

Comment: Seems to make no difference, targeting different SDKs is exactly the same result. Also my screen density and dimensions have been the same from Gingerbread up to Ice Cream Sandwich. Therefore the app should always have same dimensions.

Comment: @Neil: Could you update the AVD screenshot using the same theme as the S2 to see where are the differences more accurately?

Comment: I've added a screen shot using API 15, but I still only get 4 rows in my List, its pretty annoying!