# Samsung Galaxy S2 Emulation

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create a Galaxy S2 AVD, to test an application that doesn't render well on that phone. I followed the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings), both by `@mwalter` and by `@Lloyd`.

I can start the emulator, but I'm facing the same display problems reporter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386895/samsung-galaxy-s2-avd-official-skin-how-to-render-correct-dimensions). Unfortunately, the solution to this problem requires changing the `"abstract LCD density"`. I can't find it *anywhere* on the new SDK's UI.

I found a `hw.lcd.density` parameter in the AVD's `config.ini`, but changing it did not make any difference.

How can I make the S2 emulation behave a little more like the actual S2?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings) which helped me. Replace the contents of the config.ini file with the following:

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
abi.type=armeabi
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.device.hash=-1902399403
hw.device.manufacturer=Samsung
hw.device.name=Samsung Galaxy SII
hw.dPad=no
hw.gps=yes
hw.gsmModem=yes
hw.keyboard=no
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.ramSize=1024M
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.touchScreen=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=platforms\android-10\images\
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=galaxy_s2
skin.path=platforms\android-10\skins\GALAXY_S2
vm.heapSize=32
disk.dataPartition.size=2G
hw.camera.back=webcam0
sdcard.size=200M
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this setting:

```
hw.lcd.density
```

which is located in:

```
<ANDROID_SDK_PATH>\sdk\platforms\android-<APIversion>\skins\<YourSkin>\hardware.ini
```

from **300** to **218**.