# Setting up Galaxy S2 AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a Galaxy S2 phone, but cannot connect it to my computer since both USB slots are currently in use.  So, I am going to use the Android Virtual Device and emulate Galaxy S2.

The problem is, most of the tutorials are outdated(?).  For example, when the tutorials state you need to select a skin when you add a new virtual device; in my version, there's no such option.

This is what my options are:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRZSF.png

This is what is under the Device dropdown:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCInh.png

So, my question is, does anyone know how I can get a Galaxy S2 virtual device for Android SDK (Eclipse IDE)?

Comment: Buy a $10 USB hub and plug your phone into it. Much better and easier than a virtual device. But [Here is a maybe related SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings) question. Maybe it can help you but looks like a pain. I really recommend using a real device

Comment: I know I can get a hub and connect my phone as well, but I'd like to at least get the android virtual device to work.  The link you provided is one of those tutorials that no longer supports my version (please see screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

You can build the two files necessary. See this other answer for the process:

[Samsung Galaxy S II AVD (Android Virtual Device) Basic Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings/14189650#14189650)