# create android emulator from addon zip file

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to create a new emulator for samsung galaxy S2. Samsung provides addon zip file here, 
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-S2-Skin-for-handset-emulation

But since then Android SDK has changed a lot, I am using SDK Tools version 22.0.4

I copied the unzipped S2 addon to add-ons directory in the sdk (android-sdk-windows\add-ons), renamed to addon_galaxy_s2.

How do I detect this addon in the AVD Manager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question solves it. There is a step by step guide here.

..
[Samsung Galaxy S II AVD (Android Virtual Device) Basic Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10641744/563306)