# Emulator for Samsung galaxy S2 on the SDK Version 18

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I am completely new to Android Development and have got stuck at the very first point. I want to create a AVD for the Samsung Galaxy S2 but am not able to do so. I found many articles and questions on stack overflow like: [Samsung Galaxy S II AVD (Android Virtual Device) Basic Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings) and others but they all pertain to previous versions. I tried to map them to this one but was not able to do so.

(For the above link, i got the result that unable to load device and it did not show up in device settings under AVD after i chenged the device.xml file)

Any help in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Click on `Android Virtual Device Manager->New->Select Device as 5.1" WVGA ->Target as Android 4.3`
Other Setting is common for all devices.

Comment: @android_beginner it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea how but after complete un-install followed by reinstall all works fine. Also, i installed the latest version

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to open the same [link here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641744/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-avd-android-virtual-device-basic-settings)

I would suggest you some basic steps:

1. Go to Windo
2. Select =>AVD manager
3. Click on Device Defination
4. select New Device
5. Create new Devices (fill out)
6. Hit Create Device
7. Open the file C:\Users[user name].android\devices.xml in your favorite XML editor
8. follow step 6 of the link
9. follow step 1 to 3 of this list
10. select your device name (Samsung Galaxy II) in your case
11. close the AVD manager and follow the steps 8,9 and 10 from link.

I am only summarizing the points from the link and give you a quick heads up from the beginning in easy way: 
hope it helps:)

for skin [click here!!](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-S2-Skin-for-handset-emulation)

Comment: thanks but as i said in the question i have followed the steps but i get an error s i mentioned in the question